# When I run this code in LabVIEW it doesn't respond and I get no error. What should I do?

Tags: c++, opencv, labview

For some background, I am compiling in Visual Studio 2019 and running the code inside LabVIEW 2017. The reason I am doing it in LabVIEW is for research to control a robotic gantry. This is the vision system and it is supposed to detect rectangles.

The following code is my problem. I am fairly new to C++ and programming in general. I have done the step each line inside LabVIEW and when it stops responding is when it starts to grab the `nominalHeight`, `xfov` etc... or just when it goes into the `WBPdetection` function in general.

Where I think it might be going wrong, its possible it isn't putting the `rectWidth` and `rectHeight` into a vector. It could be that it doesn't like it when its even pixels (when it does the divide by 2 part). Another problem could be the loop isn't the right size for when its drawing the contours. But I am not sure how to figure out if this an actual problem or not since I don't get an error message.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "WBPdetection.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void show3(cv::Mat img)
{
    cv::namedWindow("MyWindow", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("MyWindow", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyWindow("MyWindow");
}

__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl WBPdetection(
    char* imgPtr, 
    int imgLineWidth, 
    int imgWidth, 
    int imgHeight, 
    double percent_size, 
    double nominalWidth, 
    double nominalHeight,
    double tolerance,
    double xfov,
    double yfov)
{
    cv::Mat img(imgHeight, imgWidth, CV_8U, (void*)imgPtr, imgLineWidth);
    cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(img.cols * percent_size, img.rows * percent_size), 0, 0);

    //PREPPING IMAGE FOR DETECTION ALGORITHIM
    cv::threshold(img, img, 125, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU);
    cv::GaussianBlur(img, img, cv::Size(5, 5), 0);
    cv::erode(img, img, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1); 
    cv::dilate(img, img, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 1, 1, 1);
    
    //USE FIND CONTOURS ALGORITHIM
    vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy; 
    cv::findContours(img, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); 
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) 
    {   approxPolyDP( cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true ); 
        boundRect[i] = cv::boundingRect( cv::Mat(contours_poly[i]) ); 
     }

    vector<vector<double>> dimRects; //ex [ [w1,h1], [w2,h2], [w3,h3], ...]
    vector<cv::Point> centerRects; //ex [ [c1], [c2], [c3], ... ]

    //PUTTING DIMENSIONS OF ALL RECTANGLES IN VECTORS
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::Point center = ((boundRect[i].tl().x + boundRect[i].br().x) / 2, (boundRect[i].tl().y + boundRect[i].br().y) / 2); //what about even pixels
        double rectWidth = (boundRect[i].br().x - boundRect[i].tl().x) * (xfov / img.cols); //might not matter tbh
        double rectHeight = (boundRect[i].tl().y - boundRect[i].br().y) * (yfov / img.rows);
        dimRects[i].push_back(rectWidth);
        dimRects[i].push_back(rectHeight);
        centerRects.push_back(center);
    }

    //DEFINING minWidth, etc... FROM tolerance AND nominalWidth
    double minWidth = nominalWidth * (1 - tolerance);
    double maxWidth = nominalWidth * (1 + tolerance);
    double minHeight = nominalHeight * (1 - tolerance);
    double maxHeight = nominalHeight * (1 + tolerance);

  // DRAWING CONTOURS AND BOUNDING RECTANGLE + CENTER
    for( int i = 0; i< dimRects.size(); i++ )
     {
       cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar(255,255,255); //creates color
       if ((dimRects[i][0] > minWidth && dimRects[i][0] < maxWidth) && (dimRects[i][1] > minHeight && dimRects[i][1] < maxHeight)) 
       {
           drawContours(img, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<cv::Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point()); 
           rectangle(img, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0); 
           circle(img, centerRects[i], 1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, cv::LINE_8);
       }
    }

    show3(img);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Labview not responding when I run this code. C++ code issue or Labview issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65742659/labview-not-responding-when-i-run-this-code-c-code-issue-or-labview-issue)

Comment: I would assume it is a problem with how you set up your *Call Library Node*. Please attach screenshots of its configuration or the VI itself.